# Convert comma delimited variable values into space delimited

Tags: text-processing

I have a property file in which a particular key has comma delimited values.

```
$cat sample.prorerties

value=alex,raj,kaly,rema
```

In my shell script I implement this property file and use the key `value` to get its values.

```
...
. sample.properties
echo $value
...
```

here is what I get as output

```
$ alex,raj,kaly,rema
```

However I am looking for a space delimited value like this

```
alex raj kaly rema
```

I know how to do this for a file however I am not certain about something which is assigned to a variable. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Incidentally: spelling: `prorerties` -> `properties`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Bash string manipulation](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation/):

```
value=alex,raj,kaly,rema
echo $value 
alex,raj,kaly,rema
```

Now replace all `,` with `' '` (space):

```
echo ${value//,/ }
alex raj kaly rema
```

---

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `tr` command.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
value=alex,raj,kaly,rema
echo $value | tr ',' ' '
```

Here's the output:

```
bash bash.sh 
alex raj kaly rema
```